# MySQL Aggregate in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

I have the following database schema:

```
Customer(ssn, name, gender, city)
Vehicle(vin, make, model, year)
BuyVehicle(bvssn, bvvin, price, year)
```

Where `BuyVehicle.bvvin` is a foreign key from `Vehicle.vin` and `BuyVehicle.bvssn` is a foreign key from `Customer.ssn`. I am trying to select names of the people who purchased vehicles at a greater price than the average of that specific vehicle.

So far, I have determined how to compute the average of the vehicles:

```
SELECT AVG(price) as avg_price, v.maker, v.model, v.year FROM BuyVehicle bv, Vehicle v, Customer c WHERE v.vin = bv.BVVIN AND c.ssn = bv.bvssn GROUP BY maker, model, year;
```

I have tried to enter a `price > avg_price` condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT AVG(price) as avg_price, v.maker, v.model, v.year FROM BuyVehicle bv, Vehicle v, Customer c WHERE v.vin = bv.BVVIN AND c.ssn = bv.bvssn AND bv.price > avg_price GROUP BY maker, model, year;
```

but MySQL tells me that the `avg_price` column does not exist. Am I taking the wrong approach to this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to use having:

```
SELECT AVG(price) as avg_price, v.maker, v.model, v.year, bv.price 
FROM BuyVehicle bv, Vehicle v, Customer c WHERE v.vin = bv.BVVIN AND c.ssn = bv.bvssn
GROUP BY maker, model, year
having bv.price > avg_price
```

Comment: I am getting: `Unknown column 'bv.price' in 'having clause'`

Comment: try to put bv.price to `select fields. SELECT AVG(price) as avg_price, v.maker, v.model, v.year , bv.price`

Comment: Very interesting issue. This query succeeds, but returns an empty set. However, if I flip the inequality to less than, it does return the rows that had a customer purchase at a lower than average price.

Comment: If you create and provide  sample tables and sample data at sqlfiddle.com people may help more. I create tables and sample data on my local server and didn't see a problem but can't sure before seeing real table structure and data...

Answer (score 0):

when working with aggregates there's a seperate clause you need to use called 'HAVING' which goes after the group by but it appears the query you are trying to write is actually more complex than that.

what is it that you want to see in the results?

I suspect you need to do a where against a sub query with the average to get what I'm guessing you want back

Comment: In the results I am looking for the names of people that purchased a vehicle that is greater than the average price for that vehicle.

Comment: ok that's going to be a join to your averages then - I'm writing on a phone so hard to copy paste...

Comment: select c.name from customer as c inner join buyvehicle as bv on bv.bvssn = c.ssn inner join ( select avg(price) as price, bvvin from buyvehicle group by bvvin) as a on a.bvvin = bv.bvvin and a.price < bv.price

Comment: if you need the above based on the three columns rather than vin then you'll need to include those inside the sub query and then again on the on clause